# Xamarin.Android - Overriding libsqlite

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sqlite, xamarin.android

I have a custom built `libsqlite3.so` which my Xamarin Droid app loads if I rename it to `libxsqlite3.so` and use DllImport ala

```
[DllImport("xsqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_libversion_number", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

When tested, the version number yields `3015002` which is the correct one. However, if I name it `libsqlite3.so`, Xamarin.Android fails to pick it up and instead picks up the native Android `libsqlite3` yielding a version number of `3007002`. Is there a way I can ask Xamarin to ignore the original sqlite3 and/or prefer mine? I am using `AndroidNativeLibrary`.

```
[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_libversion_number", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Do you have `Mono.Data.Sqlite` referenced?

Comment: I do not have ```Mono.Data.Sqlite``` referenced anywhere (fresh Xamarin Droid project). I think it just prioritizes the system lib before the included lib, which is surprising.

Comment: Assuming you are targeting APIs less then `N`... Personally I've always used a different lib name, i.e. using the `custom_sqlite3` provider of 'SQLitePCL.raw' : https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw

Comment: Even Xamarin uses a different name for their included sqlite version due to the `N` requirement of not using the system sqlite...: They use `libsqlite3_xamarin.so`

Comment: Good notes SushiHagover